# can I use this.getIntent() in any service?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

In my app I have an activity(Act1) and service (Ser1). I called the service(Ser1) through intent (i) with putting some integer value using putExtra() method and I want to get that integer value in this service is it possible? Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the service we have something like

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

so in this case the "intent" you can use to get the extras which you have send from activity.

Comment: @Sandroid : did you got the ans?